# When to use ISourceBlock or IObservable

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, system.reactive, tpl-dataflow

I need to return a collection of items with the push-model (as opposed to pull, like IEnumerable). However, I'm not sure if I should use IObservable from reactive extensions or ISourceBlock from TPL Dataflow.

They seem very similar, under what circumstances should one choose one over the other?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: @Servy: It's less clear than that.  It's more like one type of gorilla vs another similar type of gorilla, but different in some aspects.

Comment: I rephrased the question slightly. I'm not looking for a definitive answer on which one is better but rather some guidelines for choosing between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, I think the answer comes down to how are you going to use the results. If you want to process them using TPL Dataflow, return `ISourceBlock<T>`. If you're going to process them using Rx, use `IObservable<T>`.

If you don't know, I think it's better to return `ISourceBlock<T>`, because [it can be easily converted to `IObservable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160306).